# Ubuntu 12.04 install Kafka [error] File name too long

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install kafka through their [instructions](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart.html) on Ubuntu 12.04 and getting the following error

```
[error] File name too long
```

when I run

```
$ ./sbt package
```

whole error message:

```
[info] Building project Kafka 0.7.2 against Scala 2.8.0
[info]    using KafkaProject with sbt 0.7.5 and Scala 2.7.7
[info] 
[info] == core-kafka / compile ==
[info]   Source analysis: 142 new/modified, 0 indirectly invalidated, 0 removed.
[info] Compiling main sources...
[error] File name too long
[error] one error found
[info] == core-kafka / compile ==
[error] Error running compile: Compilation failed
[info] 
[info] Total time: 17 s, completed Mar 26, 2013 1:36:36 PM
[info] 
[info] Total session time: 17 s, completed Mar 26, 2013 1:36:36 PM
[error] Error during build.
```

I cam across [this explanation](http://brianoneill.blogspot.com/2012/10/file-name-too-long-in-scalasbt-on-ubuntu.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) saying that they file system is encrypted and need to mount another point and install from there.  Not too sure how to do that, or if this is the correct procedure. Hope someone can help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the `kafka` tgz file to a directory in a different filesystem.
You can list the filesytems using the `df` command. The directory you attempted to install `kafka` will probably be in the / or /home filesystem.
Then repeat the installation procedure.

As the document mentions, it's an ugly workaround.
The alternative is to re-install `ubuntu` without the encrypted filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878

Check whether directory in which you are trying to install kafka is encrypted...

try to run comment **mount | grep ecryptfs**

This Error occurs because of encrypted file system directory...